# Find roots of binomial expression by replacing some variables?

Tags: roots, quadratics, binomial-theorem

So we have the binomial expression * I might be not using the correct term,english isnt my first language*

$$ \left[1- \frac 34e^{-j2\pi\cdot f} + \frac 18e^{-j4\pi \cdot f} \right]$$

How do I find the roots using [this formula](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/b/b/a/bba46479d07af61b6e596219ce4e2cd5.png)
$$ x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} $$
If I replace $e^{-j2\pi\cdot f} $with $x$ and $e^{-j4\pi\cdot f}$ with $x^2$ I get that one $x$ is 4 and the other $2$ but those are not the correct solutions...

I know that the correct solution is

$$ \left(1- \frac 12e ^ {-j2\pi\cdot f}\right)\cdot \left(1- \frac 14e^{-j2\pi f}\right)$$

But how to get to there using the formula I said ..

Comment: Do you mean $j = \sqrt{-1}$, and $pi = \pi$? Also, I don't really see how the binomial expansion theorem would apply here...

Comment: Yes thats what I mean :)

Comment: What roots? The given term equals $\frac 38$, as $e^{-j2\pi} = 1$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot something,Im editing it.

Comment: I don't get it... This expression is just a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to factor
$$ 1 - \frac34 e^{-2\pi jf} + \frac18 e^{-4\pi jf} $$
You correctly simplify the notation by letting $x=e^{-2\pi jf}$, so the problem becomes factoring
$$ 1 - \frac34 x + \frac18 x^2 \tag{$\ast$} $$
You correctly note that you will want to find the roots of this quadratic, because they will correspond to the factors.  You correctly found the roots
$$ r_1 = 4 \quad\text{and}\quad r_2 = 2 $$
Now the problem is to understand exactly how the roots relate to the factorization.  The relation in general is
$$ ax^2+bx+c = a(x-r_1)(x-r_2) $$
(I'm guessing here, but I think you were missing the $a$ on the RHS.)
In ($\ast$) we see $a=\frac18$, so we should have
$$ 1 - \frac34 x + \frac18 x^2 = \frac18(x-4)(x-2) $$
Check that this is correct.  To get the exact form of the solution that you know, a little algebra:
$$ \frac18(x-4)(x-2) = \frac1{4\cdot 2} (x-4)(x-2)
= \frac{x-4}{4}\cdot\frac{x-2}{2}
= (\tfrac14 x - 1)(\tfrac12 x - 1) = (1 - \tfrac14 x)(1 - \tfrac12 x)$$
and now substitute $x=e^{-2\pi jf}$.

Comment: I love you,man.